# Recording video playing in a view API level<21

Tags: android, view, video-recording, screen-recording

Can we record a video playing in a texture view for Android API levels below 21(specifically for Jelly Bean and KitKat devices) . The video is streamed from a wifi camera.

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. You would be better served working with the camera manufacturer to determine how to directly receive the video stream in your own code, for recording purposes.

Comment: The camera used has 1080p resolution, so when i try to record while the stream is being played, the video playback gets stuck and disconnects as the media player does not get any data(I think it might be due to the bandwidth constrain of wifi). I am using VLC to play the stream as it has a MOV container and FFmpeg is used for recording the stream.